# TypeScript generic type inference fails

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code:

```js
interface INodeIO<T = any> {
    value: T;
}

type IODefinition = Record<string, INodeIO>;
type IODefinitionValues<D extends IODefinition> = {
    [K in keyof D]: D[K] extends INodeIO<infer T> ? T : never;
};
type CalcFunc<I extends IODefinition, O extends IODefinition> = (
    inputs: IODefinitionValues<I>
) => IODefinitionValues<O>;

type T1 = IODefinitionValues<{ hello: { value: number } }>;
type T2 = CalcFunc<{ test: { value: number } }, { ret: { value: boolean } }>;
```

Type `T1` is correctly inferred to:

```js
type T1 = { hello: number; }
```

However, `T2` is inferred to:

```js
type T2 = (inputs: IODefinitionValues<{
    test: {
        value: number;
    };
}>) => IODefinitionValues<{
    ret: {
        value: boolean;
    };
}>
```

whereas I would expect:

```js
type T2 = (inputs: { test: number; }) => { ret: boolean; }
```

This makes TS fail to correctly typecheck uses of the `CalcFunc` type. How can I change my type definitions, so the types are inferred correctly?

---

Edit: To clarify, I want the following code to be typechecked correctly:

```js
type NodeDefinition<I extends IODefinition, O extends IODefinition> = {
  setup(): { inputs: I; outputs: O };
  calculate?: CalcFunc<I, O>;
};

function defineNode<I extends IODefinition, O extends IODefinition>(def: NodeDefinition<I, O>) {}

defineNode({
  setup() {
    return {
      inputs: {
        a: { value: 3 },
        b: { value: "bar" }
      },
      outputs: {
        c: { value: false },
        d: { value: "foo" }
      }
    };
  },
  calculate(inputs) {
    return {
      // This should not work, as inputs.v is undefined
      c: inputs.v,
      // This should not work, as inputs.a is a number, while d is a string
      d: inputs.a,
      // Ideally, additional properties in the return value should not be allowed
      foo: 3
    };
  }
});
```

This code should produce multiple errors in the return value, see inline comments. However, I do not get any error from TypeScript. Also, I do not get any IntelliSense, neither for the input object nor the output object (the return value).

Interestingly, when I omit required properties from the return object (for example `d`), I do get an error.

Comment: It is inferred correctly. If you try to create a function and type it as ```T2``` and then try to access the function argument inside a function body, then you'll see that it has the correct shape. The same is true for the return value of the defined function.

Comment: @НиколайГольцев you are correct. I edited my question to provide some more context on what exactly is not working at the moment.

Comment: Your function ```defineNode``` doesn't make sense. What the purpose of this function?

Comment: It is essentially a blueprint for a node in a graph. The node has certain inputs and outputs (this is the project for which the code is: https://github.com/newcat/baklavajs). The setup function returns the "definition" of the node, meaning the inputs/outputs. Later on, the `calculate` function is called with the values of the inputs and returns the values of the outputs (dataflow programming). The `defineNode` function is essentially just a wrapper for TypeScript to help with type inference, similar to the `defineComponent` function of the Vue 3 Composition API.